# Kitchen-Docker and Systemd

Tags: docker, chef-infra, systemd, test-kitchen

I am currently using `kitchen-docker` driver for my `test kitchen` runs in order to speed up our automated cookbook tests.

However after playing for a while with this I found that every kitchen run fails if there is involved in any recipe a `service` resource, if I try to stop/start/restart a service, this is not allowed within the container and the run fails.

If I get inside the container using `kitchen login`, every time I try to use `systemctl`... I get this error message:

```
[kitchen@17c054a76e8f ~]$ sudo systemctl restart foo
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Is there any way to fix this? I am currently running this image with option `privileged: true` in `.kitchen.yml`.

Comment: This is one of many reasons that even as the maintainer of kitchen-docker, I recommend most people use dokken instead.

Comment: Is there any plan to fix this anytime Soon® or should I jump in to Kitchen-Dokken and never look back?

Comment: I mean it's not something to fix per se, just that dokken works better for this model.

Comment: There are some examples of how to configure Docker to run systemd inside the container, the driver neither helps nor hinders :) just the raw unpleasantness that is Docker.

Comment: Yes... I made systemd services work with `dokken`, but now things like `hostnamectl` makes my whole system crash when invoked inside a container. There is too much pain in this. :(

Comment: Docker for cookbook testing is a careful dance, it will never be as robust as a true VM

Comment: I was facing the similar issue. So created a service file and copied it into /etc/init.d and it works for restarting the required service. 

Do we have any better option to restart the services inside a container?

Answer (score 4):

As I didn't make the move to *kitchen-dokken* yet as well, here is the config that I use to enable *systemd* inside *kitchen-docker*:

```yaml
driver:
  name: docker
  run_command: /bin/systemd
  cap_add:
    - SYS_ADMIN
  volume:
    - /sys/fs/cgroup
```

WARNING: I assume that you are familiar with the implications of giving a container `SYS_ADMIN` capabilities (root-equivalent on the host system, read [more](https://lwn.net/Articles/486306/)).

Comment: Great idea! However I don't believe I should use this approach in an environment where many people will be using the agent where cookbooks will be tested... still great for personal usage though.